# Writing an array into a binary raw file

Tags: python, arrays, binaryfiles

I have a **numpy.ndarray** named tas with `shape (2928, 7, 9)` and I want to convert it to a **binary .raw file**. This goes fine.

Then, when I load this .raw file back into python it has the same shape as my initial tas (which is fine) but the **numbers** within this file are completely changed compared to the initial tas.

The following is what I've tried to do. If this is the wrong way of approaching this problem, does any one have other suggestions of how this could be done?

```
# Here I am loading a bunch of data

mask = np.load('Country_masks/DNK_mask.npy')
dates = np.load('date2000.npy')

temp = 'tas_EUR-44_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_historical_r3i1p1_DMI-HIRHAM5_v1_3hr_2000010100-2001010100.nc'
A = Dataset(temp, mode='r')

tas = A.variables['tas'][:,62:69,52:61]*mask[np.newaxis,62:69,52:61]
lat = B.variables['lat'][62:69,52:61]*mask[62:69,52:61]

# Here I am writing a .raw file
tas.tofile('tas_raw.raw')

# Here I am loading it again 
array_shape = tuple([len(dates)]+list(lat.shape))
data = np.memmap('tas_raw.raw',mode="r",dtype=np.single,shape=array_shape);
```

Comment: can you provide some sample input data and required output

Comment: Yes, data can be found here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlJG9g1WlnmlhDC1WfgR1ljtI67E

The required output should be a .raw file. But then it has to have the ability of being converted back to a ndarray file containing the same content as tas